# VBE can still edit READ ONLY version of Personal.xlsb

Tags: vbe

Excel Visual Basic Editor does two things:
1. Doesn't show 'Read only' in the file title of Personal.xlsb, so the base version of the file looks the same in the editor as the read only version.
2. Allows you to edit the Read Only version, without any warning.

So when I have multiple instances of Excel open it is very easy to accidentally edit the Read Only Version of my personal.xlsb and I only realise this is what I have done when I try to save and it says it is a read-only file. So then I have to decide which version is the most complete and save that one in XLSTART, or if I have only done a little coding, transfer the changed code from the read only file to the base file.

Driving me crazy. I do a lot of coding and run some lengthy macros, so like to be able to open multiple instances of Excel.

Is there any way to make the read only version of Personal.xlsb just that - NO EDITING available, or give a warning that you are about to edit a read only OR at least show the read only part of the file name in the VBE window.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

After much fiddling with protected view, blocked files, trust centre etc, I finally came up with this solution:
In VBE, right click on the file (in this case my Personal.xlsb). Click on VBAProjectProperties and go to Protection tab.
Check the *Lock Project for viewing* box.
Enter a (very easy) password. Close the file and re-open or restart Excel.

The xlsb file will open as normal. The first time you try to edit the project in VBE, it asks for the password. Once you give the password you can edit this instance of the file to your heart's content but if you open another instance of Excel, and hence a new read-only version of the Personal.xlsb, the password requirement is in place, so if you try to edit the VBA in this file you will be prompted again for your password.

Of course, this doesn't work if the read-only personal.xlsb is the instance you happen to be in when you first go to edit in VBE, and you think you are unlocking the original instance, but I have found this usually that isn't the case with me. I usually edit the personal sometime in the day before needing to open a second instance of Excel. It has already saved me a couple of times, the request for password has alerted me to the fact that I am in the read-only version's VBE instance. Not perfect, but is working for me...:)